# Show that the improper integral is conditionally convergent

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> Find out if the following improper integral converges absolutely, converges conditionally or diverges:
>   $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\,dx.$$

I'm struggling to show that the integral converges conditionally (I already found that the original integral converges).

I tried to use comparison tests, but had no success. Here are a couple of my tries:

> 1) $$\int_0^\infty \left|\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\right|\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\left|\cos(x)\right|}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\,dx\le\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\,dx;$$
>   this one didn't really helped me, since the last integral diverges.
>
> 2) $$\int_0^\infty \left|\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\right|\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\left|\cos(x)\right|}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\,dx\ge\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\,dx;$$
>   this one seems that it might help, but I couldn't find a way to use it.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: I think it converges by Dirichlet test, and it diverges in absolute value.

Comment: That is correct, but I couldn't show that it diverges in absolute value. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral converges by Dirichlet test.

To tackle the absolute convergence, note that $|\cos(x)|\geq \cos(x)^2=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}2$ and use Dirichlet again to conclude that you have the sum of a convergent and a divergent integral. Hence the integral with absolute values diverges.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck right about that part. Will give it a try again :)

Comment: @GabrielRomon (+1), this one is much more elegant. :)

Answer (score 1):

To show that the integral *does not* converge absolutely:

You are integrating over the interval
$$(0,\infty)=(0,\pi/4]\cup (\pi/4, 3\pi/4]\cup (3\pi/4, 5\pi/4]\cup (5\pi/4, 7\pi/4]\space\cup\space ...$$

Note that on the even-numbered intervals $(\pi/4,3\pi/4],(5\pi/4,7\pi/4],$ and so on, it holds that $|\cos(x)|>1/\sqrt{2}$. This means that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{|\cos(x)|}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}dx &\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\pi k-\pi/4}^{\pi k+\pi/4} \frac{|\cos(x)|}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}dx \\
&\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\pi k-\pi/4}^{\pi k+\pi/4} \frac{1/\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}dx \\
&\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\pi k-\pi/4}^{\pi k+\pi/4} \frac{1/\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x}}dx \\
&\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\pi k-\pi/4}^{\pi k+\pi/4} \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{2x}} \\
\end{align}$$

Then evaluate the integral in each term of the series and evaluate the convergence or divergence of the series. Can you take it from here?

Comment: That's a strange way to split the intervals... why not just use $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty(n\pi,(n+1)\pi)$?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think that I could come up with that. It looks more complicated than what is expected from me as a first year student. I think it should be solved through the use of comparison tests and Abbel\Dirichlet tests, at least that's the subject of the worksheet...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Because $|\cos x|$ has no nonzero lower bound on such intervals. I’m splitting it up that way so that I get infinitely many intervals on which $|\cos x|$ is greater than some positive value, demonstrating divergence when I split it into a series.

Comment: $\cos(x)$ is clearly $0$ somewhere on $(\pi/4,3\pi/4)$, for example. In fact bounding the $\cos$ really isn't a good strategy. You should bound the $\frac1{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt x}$ instead.

Comment: Should be $[k\pi-\pi/4,k\pi+\pi/4]$. And +1 for the method. I think it's perfectly natural. Also you can replace each integrand again by setting $x=$ upper bound of each interval, which gives a smaller constant integrand.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\int_0^M \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} < \infty$, you can ignore some finite initial interval. Also, notice that the denominator is
$$
\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+1} = \sqrt{x} (2 + O(x^{-1})).
$$
Using your attempt on 2), if you use that
$$
\cos^2 x = \frac{\cos 2x + 1}{2},
$$
and consider $M$ large enough you get for some positive constant $c$ that
$$
\int_M^{\infty} \frac{|\cos x|}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+1}} \ dx
\geq c \left( \int_M^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2x}{\sqrt{x}} \ dx + \int_M^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \ dx \right).
$$
Since you already know that the first integral converges and the second integral diverges, you conclude that the original integral is not absolutely convergent.